# Using a void Subject to Signal an Event

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is using a `void` Subject to signal that something has happened a good practice?

I'm curious as to whether or not there is a better way to signal some event and if I should restructure my code.

A more complete example of this is:

*Custom Service*

```
public data: Subject<Data> = new Subject<Data>();

public save: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
```

*Component A*

```
public data: Data[] = [];

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = someApiCall;
}

public saveData(): void {
    this.myService.save.next();

    // do something with data after it being updated
}

private updateData(): void {
    this.myService.data.subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
    });
}
```

*Component B*

```
@Input()
public data: Data[] = [];

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onSave();
}

private onSave(): void {
    this.myService.save.subscribe(() => {
        this.myService.data.next(this.data);
    });
}
```

Component B has as an `Input` from the data that comes from the `ngOnInit` in Component A.

When the `Save` button is clicked in Component A, Component B listens to the event and emits the data is has received from its input back to Component A. Component A then receives the data through `updateData()` and sets it there.

I'm only using a `Subject` in this case to signal that the `Save` has happened, but I am not passing any data around.

Thoughts?

Comment: You created void subject, where do you use it?

Comment: @siva636, forgot to update the name in the service.

Comment: Generally I think it is not a good idea to call `next()` on an Observable from within the callbacks passed to the `subscribe()` method. And this is what happens in the `onSave()` method of ComponentB. 


It seems that what you want to achieve is to pass `data` instance variable of ComponentB to ComponentA any time ComponentA executes the `saveData()` method. But then it is not clear who saves what, so it is difficult to suggest anything, at least for me.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, no. You probably shouldn’t call .next() on a Subject imperatively to signify an event. [This article](https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93)by Ben Lesh explains why it’s not the Rx way.

Ideally, you’d construct an Observable from the event and subscribe to it wherever you want to react to that event.

Comment: That article sums it up well. Generally speaking, unless the use case calls for multi-casting, then you should generally steer clear of using Subject.